# error on streambuilder firebase how to solve

Tags: android, flutter, gridview, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get all user posts that he create and show these on both gridview and listview (column)
now i already have my query on stream. dart analyser dont show me error but when i run the app in debug i will get an error 'Colum's childre must not contains any null values, but a null value was found at index 0'

this is my widget for grid and listview

```
 Container buildUserPosts() {


return Container(
    child:  StreamBuilder <QuerySnapshot> (
      stream: playlistsRef.where('authorId', isEqualTo: widget.userId).snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot){
        if(!snapshot.hasData){
          return Center(
            child: new CircularProgressIndicator(
              valueColor: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.white
              ),
              strokeWidth: 3.0,
            ),
          );
        }

else if (view == "grid") {
          final List <_PlaylistLikeRecord> records = snapshot.data.documents
              .map((snapshot) =>_PlaylistLikeRecord.fromSnapshot(snapshot))
              .toList();if (records == null){
 return Container();}else {
 return GridView.count(
     crossAxisCount: 3,
     childAspectRatio: 1.0,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.5),
     mainAxisSpacing: 1.5,
     crossAxisSpacing: 1.5,
     shrinkWrap: true,
     physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
     children: <Widget>[
       GridTile(
           child: new Column(
             children: records
                 .map((record) => _buildListItem(context, record))
                 .toList(),
           )
       ),
     ]);}
} else if (view == "feed") {
          final List <_PlaylistLikeRecord> records = snapshot.data.documents
              .map((snapshot) =>_PlaylistLikeRecord.fromSnapshot(snapshot))
              .toList();if(records == null){
return Container();}else{
return Column(
  children: records
      .map((record) => _buildListItem(context, record))
      .toList(),

);}

        }
      },
    ));}
```

And my gesturedetector on item tap

```
 Widget _buildListItem(BuildContext context, _PlaylistLikeRecord record) {

GestureDetector(
    onTap: () =>   Navigator.push(context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PlaylistsDetailsPage(

            imageUrl: record.playlisturl, title: record.title


        ))),
    child: Image.network(record.playlisturl, fit: BoxFit.cover));}
```

Comment: are you missing return statement in _buildListItem() function?

Comment: No, the problem is near builduserPosts() children who return error

Comment: your error says, column widget children is null, so are you sure "record" in _buildLIstItem is not null. Try to add `if(record==null) return Container()` at top of _buildListItem() function.

Comment: I do this but same error. It's means that is not null

Comment: I updated the code see yourself

Comment: return container() I said earlier should be inside _buildListItem function,
`Widget _buildLIstItem(...,...){ if(record==null) return Container(); ...}` like that.